# fail to use invokeExact of MethodHandle on dynamic load class object

Tags: java-7, methodhandle

I have some demo code as follwing.

```
  Class<?> myClass = cl.loadClass("com.hp.ac.scriptengine.test." + generateClassName);
  Object my_obj = myClass.newInstance();
  MethodType mt; 
  MethodHandle mh;
  MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();            
  mt = MethodType.methodType(void.class, int.class);
  mh = lookup.findVirtual(my_obj.getClass(), "ToDoit", mt);
  mh.invokeExact(my_obj,1);
```

here '"com.hp.ac.scriptengine.test." + generateClassName' is a generated class.
I got the message as follows.

```
java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException: (I)V cannot be called as (Ljava/lang/Object;I)V
                 at com.hp.ac.scriptengine.test.compliebyCommandline.main(compliebyCommandline.java:138)
```

Here line 138 is `mh.invokeExact(my_obj,1);`'

I tried that demo code(such as ... `mh.invokeExact("daddy",'d','n')...`) in Java 7 API document. It works fine. Such call(`mh.invokeExact("daddy",'d','n')`)just invoke `(CC)Ljava/lang/String` other than `(Ljava/lang/String;CC)Ljava/lang/String`. 
But why, in my code, `mh.invokeExact(my_obj,1)` invoke (Ljava/lang/Object;I)V other than (I)V ?

Comment: For one thing, you need to cast my_obj to your generated class type (or a subtype) -- the lack of a cast is why invokeExact uses Ljava/lang/Object; as the first argument type.  But I'm not sure why the method handle claims to be (I)V despite being virtual.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is with int.class. Try Integeer.class or Integer.TYPE instead.